# Convert Map<K, List<V>> to Map<K, V> where V have 2 lists of objects

Tags: java, list, lambda, java-stream

Model:

```
Year{
 int year;
}

ObjectB{
 ObjectBA bb;  <- ObjectBA{int value}
 ObjectBB ba;  <- ObjectBB{int value}
}

ObjectC{
  List<ObjectBA>
  List<ObjectBB>
}
```

How to convert:
`Map<Year, List<ObjectB>>` 
to
`Map<Year, ObjectC>`
where Object C have all element from ObjectB

I already have:

```
var result = inputMap.entrySet().stream()
             .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                        e -> e.getKey(),
                        e -> e.getValue().stream().
                                map(
                                       value -> value.bb().getValue()
                                ).toList())
                );
```

i need something that give me multimple list in Object, like:

```
 map(
       new ObjectC(
          value -> value.ba().getValue(),
          value -> value.bb().getValue()
    ).toList())
```

Comment: If you have Guava, then with the right constructor for `ObjectC`, you can say `Maps.transformValues(inputMap, v -> new ObjectC(v.bb, v.ba));`. Even with streams, Guava has clearer ways of expressing some common operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've got looks pretty good already. Just replace the value mapper with `e -> convert(e.getValue())` where `convert` is like the function below that converts a `List<ObjectB>` into an `ObjectC`:

```java
ObjectC convert(List<ObjectB> list) {
    ObjectC c = new ObjectC();
    for (ObjectB b : list) {
        c.ba.add(b.ba);
        c.bb.add(b.bb);
    }
    return c;
}
```

Or if you'd prefer to stick with just using streams, try `Stream#collect` like so:

```java
e.getValue().stream().collect(
        () -> new ObjectC(),
        (c, b) -> {
                c.ba.add(b.ba);
                c.bb.add(b.bb);
        },
        (c1, c2) -> {
                c1.ba.addAll(c2.ba);
                c1.bb.addAll(c2.bb);
        }
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Also for the converter. I'm going to have a lot of such converts so it might be useful!

Comment: If you own and can modify the `ObjectC` class, I would recommend adding a convenience method 
`void add(ObjectB b) {
    this.ba.add(b.ba);
    this.bb.add(b.bb);
}` so you don't have to repeat that everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

For possible future reference I offer the following:

The first is a simple loop based solution. Of the two, this is more straightforward and probably more efficient.

- iterate the map's entry set.
- create two lists, one for each field of `ObjectC`
- then iterate over the `ObjectB` list and copy the objects to their lists
- then create an instance of `ObjectC` with the newly created lists

I used getters and and a constructor but direct assignments could be used if the fields are not private.

```
for (Year y : map.keySet()) {
    List<ObjectBA> listBA = new ArrayList<>();
    List<ObjectBB> listBB = new ArrayList<>();
    for (ObjectB b : map.get(y)) {
        listBA.add(b.getBA());
        listBB.add(b.getBB());
    }
    result.put(y, new ObjectC(listBA, listBB));
}
```

This method uses streams.

- stream the entrySet.
- and create a new ObjectC using the constructor.
- the arguments to the constructor are themselves, streams of the source lists
- a mapping is performed to get the objects (BA and BB)
- and a list is returned to fulfill the requirements of the constructor.

```
Map<Year, Object> result = map.entrySet().stream().collect(
        Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey,
                e -> new ObjectC(
                e.getValue().stream().map(ObjectB::getBA)
                        .toList(),
                e.getValue().stream().map(ObjectB::getBB)
                        .toList())));
```